# How to get all "id" values from JSON response?

Tags: python, api, request

I have tried this easy value parsing but it did not work. I am able to get all response and if there is single value I can easily get value but I could not catch why I am getting this error.

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

I want to get all "id" from this JSON response.

Here is my code:

```
def get_api_all(api):
    r = requests.get(f'{base_url}/{api}/')
    return r.status_code, r.json()

 def test_get_person(self):
        status_code, data =get_api_all('persons')
        ids = []
        for i in data['id']:
         print(i['id'])
```

and here is my sample response in json format:

```
[
   {
      "id":"b9f2d28c-57dc-4381-a752-ac36611ab51a",
      "first_name":"Arnold",
      "last_name":"Schwarzenegger",
      "birth_year":1947
   },
   {
      "id":"b636e887-7402-4eda-885f-549ea9792116",
      "first_name":"Charlize",
      "last_name":"Theron",
      "birth_year":1975
   },
   {
      "id":"c22c7475-bd4b-4dfd-ab3b-eb27ef4cb59f",
      "first_name":"Brad",
      "last_name":"Pitt",
      "birth_year":1963
   },
   {
      "id":"33c22f9d-cfc4-4733-986a-61e1a73cee8e",
      "first_name":"Patrick",
      "last_name":"Stewart",
      "birth_year":1940
   },
   {
      "id":"a0c54b47-35b1-4894-bccf-7bac9ade8f41",
      "first_name":"dumm",
      "last_name":"Stewart",
      "birth_year":1940
   },
   {
      "id":"a43fca0c-2a49-49be-902f-ec48ac4b57cb",
      "first_name":"Patrick",
      "last_name":"Stewart",
      "birth_year":1940
   } ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake there:

```
for i in data['id']:
    print(i['id'])
```

should be:

```
for i in data:
    print(i['id'])
```

because data is a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary. A list has no key, therefore `data['id']` raises an error.